# Windows 7 -ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME

Tags: java, ant

[image]

Hi All,

I set ANT_HOME path but while trying to use ant -version i get the error "ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME"

Attached pic for reference.

Pls help.

Answer (score 9):

You have ANT_HOME set 2 times :

1. as User environment variable ANT_HOME=%ANT_HOME%\bin
2. as System environment variable ANT_HOME=C:\ant-apache-1.9.3

Set ANT_HOME=C:\ant-apache-1.9.3 either as User variable **OR** as System variable but not both !
Afterwards put %ANT_HOME%\bin to your System Path variable

**ANT_HOME has to be set to the rootfolder of your Ant installation** => C:\ant-apache-1.9.3 in your case, it's similar to setting JAVA_HOME.
Including \bin is wrong !

Test your ant installation via cmd :

```
C:\Users\someuser>ant
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

=> OK
For more details about your ant installation use :

```
C:\Users\someuser>ant -diagnostics
------- Ant diagnostics report -------
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013

-------------------------------------------
 Implementation Version
-------------------------------------------
core tasks     : 1.9.3 in file:/C:/ant193/lib/ant.jar

-------------------------------------------
 ANT PROPERTIES
-------------------------------------------
ant.version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
ant.java.version: 1.7
Is this the Apache Harmony VM? no
Is this the Kaffe VM? no
Is this gij/gcj? no
ant.core.lib: C:\ant193\lib\ant.jar
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `ANT_HOME`, but you haven't added the `ANT_HOME/bin` directory to the `PATH` variable.

You need to modify your `PATH` variable in Environment variables like this

`%ANT_HOME%\bin;` Just add it and the end of your `PATH` variable value

I've just added the `ANT` bin directory to the existing `PATH` variable. Please follow this [link](http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/doc/ot-userguide13/xhtml/installing/windows_installingant.html)

Comment: I already added ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin to the path variable but it gave me the same error. Where the SET PATH = %PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin; has to be added? system variables?

Comment: Do you have `PATH` in your environment variables? Checout this [link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) on how to set `PATH`.

Comment: follow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607664/error-installing-ant-ant-home-is-set-incorrectly/32183652#32183652

Answer (score 1):

Delete the ANT_HOME path variable, the message is ACTUALLY saying it needs to use a project specific path. You are overriding it by setting ANT_HOME.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10