# Ant and Windows 8.1

Tags: ant, windows-8

I'm trying to set Ant on my Win 8.1 and, of course, I've followed some hints already posted.

When I try to run Ant that's what I get:

```
C:\Users\Marco>ant
ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.
```

Checking my path:

```
C:\Users\Marco>echo %ANT_HOME%
C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.3

C:\Users\Marco>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

Again in my PATH:

```
C:\Users\Marco>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\apa
che-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-
ant-1.9.3\lib;D:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools;D:\Andr
oidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x
86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:
\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\Syst
em32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Win
dows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DA
L;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)
\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Op
enCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Prog
ram Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Marco\node_modules\cordova\bin;D:\AndroidSDK\adt-bund
le-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\
Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I've tried everything reading other posts but seems that nothing is right to launch ANT; what I'm missing?

Comment: Try to put Ant into a directory without spaces in its name (and maybe the JDK as well)

Comment: Thanks; did it and also fix missing lib

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing Ant: ANT\_HOME is set incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607664/error-installing-ant-ant-home-is-set-incorrectly)