# PhoneGap: 'ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.'

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant, npm

I'm using PhoneGap with the massive chain of stuff installed that it tends to require. Currently, running on the command line gives:

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
$ phonegap -v
3.5.0-0.20.10
$ cordova -v
3.5.0-0.2.7
$ npm -v
1.4.21
```

But compiling with PhoneGap or Cordova yields:

```
$ phonegap local build android
[phonegap] compiling Android...
cp: no such file or directory: E:\Projects\Tets\icon.png

cp: no such file or directory: E:\Projects\Tets\res\icon\ios\icon-72.png

ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.
```

Inspecting the paths:

```
ANT_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/ant/ant
PATH=/usr/local/bin:<standard path data...>:/cygdrive/c/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/ant/ant/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/npm
```

When installing vis `npm install ant`, I am met with this warning:

```
npm WARN engine ant@0.2.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.30","npm":"1.4.21"})
```

It appears to install fine, I just had to manually add the path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Follow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607664/error-installing-ant-ant-home-is-set-incorrectly/32183652#32183652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Delete the ANT_HOME path variable, the message is ACTUALLY saying it needs to use a project specific path. You are overriding it by setting ANT_HOME.

Comment: Can you suggest how to write project specific path ?