# How to install Apache Ant on Windows 7

Tags: java, apache, ant

I want to install Apache ant on windows. Here is some information below:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html
- [Error installing Ant: ANT_HOME is set incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607664/installing-ant-ant-home-is-set-incorrectly-on-windows-7)

I followed its descriptions and step by step but it still cannot work.
I think the entire environment variables I set are correct. May please someone helps me? And some copies from cmd.

```
C:\>echo %ANT_HOME%
C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4

C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34

C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_34"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_34-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.9-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>ant 
is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

My Ant version is 1.9.4

Comment: Rather than linking to some generic manuals / questions: describe what exactly you have done and what happens when you attempt to run ant. Thanks.

Comment: Did you include the bin directory in the path?

Comment: Thanks for your advice and edit. I wanna use metro in web service. Before it I need install apache ant.

Comment: I think I include bin in there. Here is part of my path variable 

C:\>echo %PATH%

;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin

Comment: Please add these details as a proper edit to your question. What happens when you try to execute `ant`?

Comment: When I typing ant in cmd. It can not execute. This command             "    ant -Dtomcat.home={Tomcat Installation Directory} -f metro-on-tomcat.xml install "

Comment: Please add these details as a proper edit to your question. Define "it can not execute". Do you get an error?

Comment: cmd --> ant --> is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the path is not set properly.

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
set ANT_HOME=D:\software\apache-ant-1.9.4
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

Edit: fixed PATH definition

Answer (score 0):

**Change your path From:**
C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34

**To:**
C:\Progra~1\apache-ant-1.9.4
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_34

When setting the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Change you path , not install on `C:\Program Files\`

Add **Path**, like:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```