# Installing ANT - unable to locate tools.jar

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to install Apache Ant on my system, while setting the path variable. I have jdk installed on my system. I set the ANT_HOME environment variable to where ant is located on the system, i.e, `F:\apache-ant-1.9.6\`, and the path variable to `F:\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin`.

[image: path variable]
[image: ANT_HOME variable]

But when I test if ANT is installed correctly by typing `ant -version` on cmd , I get this error:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.
0_25\lib\tools.jar
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
```

[While reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607664/error-installing-ant-ant-home-is-set-incorrectly), they say tools.jar in included in jdk and not jre. But I have correctly installed jdk, and set the environment variable correctly for that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also facing same issue but after research of an 1 hour I got a solution.

1. In system variable set your jdk path in starting.
2. Variable name: Path
3. Variable value: **C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin**;C:\Users\SESA401780\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools;C:\Users\SESA401780\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;...
4. Enter Ok Ok ... and
5. Open new cmd

Answer (score 3):

When you actually go to the location specified by ant build it'll not have tools.jar.
The error is misleading and wrong. It is just because either JAVA_HOME is not defined or not set properly. Once it is done, error would get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.  It looks like the java.exe you are running from the command line is finding your JRE, not your JDK.  Set JAVA_HOME to the location of your JDK, and move the bin directory of your JDK to be before the JRE in your PATH and try again, should work.

Comment: But the java programs are compiling and executing correctly , I have been compiling java programs from the past 1 year. If the JAVA_HOME variable is not correctly set , how come java programs run fine?

Comment: Most likely because javac.exe (not java.exe) is being found from the JDK and that works properly.  But when something (ant.bat I believe) is invoking java.exe it's running a different executable from a different folder (from the JRE) and thus not finding tools.jar automatically.

Comment: okay , I have tried to set the java path and the ant path again, deleting the old ones , still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

> ```
> Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.
> 0_25\lib\tools.jar
> ```

`tools.jar` is expected to be in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8`,
but it's not there.
That path looks suspiciously like a JRE path,
not a JDK.

Make sure to set `JAVA_HOME` to the path of your JDK. Then it should work.
It seems that currently `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to the path of the JRE,
not the JDK.

Comment: But I have set the JAVA_HOME variable to jdk and not jre, still getting this strange error

Comment: Just to get things clear, please confirm this: on the command line, when you do `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, it prints the path to JDK. And then when you do `ant -version` it prints an error message about expected `tools.jar` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.
0_25`, which is different from the JDK path. Right?